# combining predefined aesthetics (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics, non-standard-evaluation

I have a function that optionally accepts predefined aesthetics (for `ggplot2`). This can be in one of several forms, including

```r
mapping <- aes(color = c(cyl, gear))
mapping
# Aesthetic mapping: 
# * `colour` -> `c(cyl, gear)`
```

or programmatically as

```r
mapping <- aes(color = c(.data[["cyl"]], .data[["gear"]]))
mapping
# Aesthetic mapping: 
# * `colour` -> `c(.data[["cyl"]], .data[["gear"]])`
```

(I'm using `color=` here, but really I'm using `group=` and `subgroup=` in various ways. I'm simplifying to `color=` here for simplicity.)

My function cannot control if or how the caller defines `mapping` (it defaults to `NULL`), it can either be using symbols (first example) or one of the programmatic options like `.data` (second example), but internally after I adjust/augment the data, I need to add a variable to that aesthetic.

I can combine *different* aesthetics using `c`, as in

```r
mapping <- aes(color = factor(cyl))
othermap1 <- aes(x = mpg, y = disp)
ggplot(mtcars, mapping = aes(!!!c(mapping, othermap1))) +
  geom_path()
```

(The plot itself doesn't matter much, just that it works.)

[image: simple grouped ggplot lines]

If I want to add a variable to the `color=` aesthetic, I don't know how to best do it.

```r
othermap2 <- aes(color = gear)
```

I would like to be able to get the effect of `color=` combined, with an result similar to the manual:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, mapping = aes(mpg, disp, color = interaction(cyl, gear))) +
  geom_path()
```

This is all programmatic, and I would prefer to allow the user to provide a "real" `mapping=` argument (e.g., `mapping=aes(...)`) in the call to my function.

I think one possible way is to require the user to provide a named-list of variables if they intend to assign `color=`, such as `mapping=list(group="cyl")` and internally I'll augment/merge and then create the `.data[[x]]` aesthetics internally ... but I really would prefer to continue to allow the user to use `mapping=aes(..)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some rlang magic to manipulate the mapping.
Briefly, we just assign the new aesthetic if it was abent, otherwise we create a new call combining the two expressions.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

combine_mapping <- function(user, fixed, fun = interaction) {
  names(user)  <- standardise_aes_names(names(user))
  names(fixed) <- standardise_aes_names(names(fixed))
  fun <- enexpr(fun)
  for (var in names(fixed)) {
    inject <- quo_get_expr(fixed[[var]])
    if (var %in% names(user)) {
      expr <- quo_get_expr(user[[var]])
      user[[var]] <- call2(fun, !!!list(inject, expr))
    } else {
      user[[var]] <- fixed[[var]]
    }
  }
  user
}
```

Some demonstrations

```r
user_mapping <- aes(mpg, disp, colour = cyl)

# Case of missing aesthetic
combine_mapping(aes(mpg, disp), aes(colour = cyl))
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `x`      -> `mpg`
#> * `y`      -> `disp`
#> * `colour` -> `cyl`

# Combining aesthetic
combine_mapping(user_mapping, aes(colour = gear))
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `x`      -> `mpg`
#> * `y`      -> `disp`
#> * `colour` -> `interaction(gear, cyl)`

# Multiple aesthetics
combine_mapping(user_mapping, aes(colour = gear, x = cty))
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `x`      -> `interaction(cty, mpg)`
#> * `y`      -> `disp`
#> * `colour` -> `interaction(gear, cyl)`

# Other function to combine
combine_mapping(user_mapping, aes(colour = gear), fun = paste0)
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `x`      -> `mpg`
#> * `y`      -> `disp`
#> * `colour` -> `paste0(gear, cyl)`

# Works in plot
ggplot(mtcars, combine_mapping(aes(mpg, disp, colour = cyl), aes(colour = gear))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you teunbrand! This seems strong enough to include in your `ggh4x`, do you think? I've extended it slightly to change the formals to `(mapping, ..., fun=interactive)`, where `...` is zero or more additional `aes(.)` objects. More testing is justified to see if I understand it well enough and no corner-cases exist, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this gives you a direction on how to go about the problem.  This is vectorized such that all the repeated aesthetics will be combined:

```
merge_aes <- function(mappings, ...){
    a <- unlist(list(mappings, ...))
    nms <- names(a)
    names(a) <- NULL
    f <- quote(interaction)
    b <- names(which(table(nms) > 1))
    if(!length(b)) return(a)
    fn <- \(x)if(length(x)>1) as.call(c(f,x))   else x
    g <- unlist(tapply(sapply(a, rlang::quo_squash), nms, fn))
    eval(as.call(c(quote(aes), g)))
}

mapping <- aes(color = factor(cyl))
othermap1 <- aes(x = mpg, y = disp)
othermap2 <- aes(color = gear)

merge_aes(mapping, othermap1,
                    othermap2,
                    aes(group = vs),
                    aes(group = am),
                    aes(shape = factor(am)),
                    aes(shape = factor(vs)))
Aesthetic mapping: 
* `x`      -> `mpg`
* `y`      -> `disp`
* `colour` -> `interaction(factor(cyl), gear)`
* `group`  -> `interaction(vs, am)`
* `shape`  -> `interaction(factor(am), factor(vs))`
```

---

```
ggplot(mtcars) + merge_aes(mapping, othermap1, othermap2) + 
    geom_path()
```

[image]

Comment: Very impressive, thank you Onyambu! My mastery of NSE is clearly lacking! The main difference I can find between this and teunbrand's answer is the return value from this must be external to `ggplot(.)` and `geom_*(.)`, since it returns a list of aesthetics instead of combining them. Thank you again!

Comment: @r2evans you can have it inside the `ggplot(.)`

Comment: @r2evans This does not return a list of aes. it combines all the aes together. You can pass as many aes and all will be merged. One difference between this and the other answer, is that the other one takes only two mappings. If given a list of mappings, or more than two mappings, this will still work.

Comment: `ggplot(mtcars, merge_aes(mapping, othermap1, othermap2)) + geom_point()` works as expected. I believe you had the first version of my code whereby i was returning a list. I did update the code to have all of them to be merged as one. Try the new `merge_aes` function

Comment: My apologies, I must have not reloaded the environment correctly, I see that it works as expected. Sorry for the noise, Onyambu, and thanks again for the answer!